# When calling MediaProjectionManager to take a screenshot, the screenshot permission box pops up every time. How can I set the cancellation?

Tags: java, android, linux

Screen capture tripartite app screen.

Comment: need more information for answering this question.

Comment: How to capture the three-party application screen？

Answer (score 0):

To include screenshot function your app, you need to grand superuser permission. In other words, third-party apps can only take a screenshot on a rooted device or your app should be installed as a system app only then it's possible.